# Unable to run R2 Simulation

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I am new to ROS. I was trying to build existing R2 (Robonaut 2) project on ROS Indigo. I was following the steps from the book named "Programming Robots with ROS" (page no : 232). I was trying to run r2_mime.py. But whenever i run r2_mime.py, it shows error like :

[rospack] Error: package 'r2_description' not found

[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1454006577.536794402, 287.060000000]: Error retrieving file [package://r2_description/meshes/Finger_Dist.dae]: Package [r2_description] does not exist

Can anyone please help me what i am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225329/unable-to-run-r2-simulation/) by [baila](https://answers.ros.org/users/25509/baila/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2016-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure you've cloned and the nasa_r2_simulator and nasa_r2_common (instructions are page 172 in the copy I have) into your catkin workspace (i.e. run the "git clone" commands in chessbot/src). You should also make sure that you've sourced the devel/setup.bash file before you try run the r2_mime.py script.

r2_description is in the [nasa_r2_common repository](https://bitbucket.org/nasa_ros_pkg/nasa_r2_common/src/15ec0b187aba8ca15e6906c2f9325e4b0d4b45ae/r2_description/?at=master). Therefore you need to get the repository, build it into your catkin workspace, and source the setup.bash for that workspace before you can run code that uses it.

If you have more problems, please describe the state of your workspace and the commands that you've typed in and report the issue on https://github.com/osrf/rosbook/issues

---

Originally posted by [jackie](https://answers.ros.org/users/23055/jackie/) with karma: 296 on 2016-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [baila](https://answers.ros.org/users/25509/baila/) on 2016-01-29**:
Thank you jackie.  **"You should also make sure that you've sourced the devel/setup.bash file before you try run the r2_mime.py script."**  solves my problem. Can you please explain why do we run that command before any action?

**Comment by [jackie](https://answers.ros.org/users/23055/jackie/) on 2016-01-29**:
In a catkin workspace, you need to source the devel/setup.bash in order to configure your PATH and your ROS environment to find the files that you built in the workspace. See page 14 of the book, or the catkin tutorials http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying

**Comment by [Jumuu](https://answers.ros.org/users/27754/jumuu/) on 2016-08-15**:
I also try to build the r2_mime into another package inside the workspace. What are the dependencies that I need to run those r2 code?